# Happy Birthday songs in Spanish

Tags: diferencias-regionales, música

The most recognized song in the English language is ["Happy Birthday to You"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday_to_You) (the common song sung on someone's birthday). What songs in Spanish are traditionally sung on birthdays (and what are the lyrics)? Are there a handful that are most common, or does every country tend to have its own?

Comment: I am closing this for two reasons.  1) It's essentially a list question.  And 2) It's really a culture question, and not a Spanish-language question.  A similar question might do better on the proposed [Latin American Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36499/latin-american-culture?referrer=4tyFLuUhaxyfrPFYAQiFkg2) site.

Comment: @Flimzy: Good point. Culture and language often overlap (I wouldn't consider someone 100% fluent in Spanish if they didn't know how to sing along on someone's birthday), but otherwise this doesn't have much to do with the language specifically.

Comment: Yes, you're right that language and culture go hand in hand.  But even so, asking this same about English-language birthday songs on English L&U I'm sure would be closed as off-topic. Culture is a _huge_ area of study, and while it does have some overlap with language, it is much broader than any language site ought to try to cover. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are heaps of different ways to sing the Happy Birthday Song and they are regional. When I attend my University's Spanish Club and it's someones birthday everyone starts singing a different song. (But in the end we usually sing the first version I list here, probably due to the ethnicities of the people at the club.)

In Argentina I sang:

> Que los cumplas feliz,
>
> Que los cumplas feliz,
>
> Que los cumplas a (name),
>
> Que los cumplas feliz.

But there are many variations, sometimes a completely different song, sometimes only slightly different.

> Feliz Cumpleaños a ti
>
> Feliz Cumpleaños a ti
>
> Feliz Cumpleaños a (name)
>
> Feliz Cumpleaños a ti

Another one:

> Cumpleaños feliz
>
> cumpleaños feliz
>
> te deseamos (name)
>
> cumpleaños feliz.

A Colombian friend sung this:

> Que los cumpla feliz,
>
> que los vuelva a cumplir,
>
> que los siga cumpliendo,
>
> hasta el año 3000.

Sorry I don't know which regions sing which songs, if anyone does feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score 4):

In Spain, we usually sing the Happy Birthday song with the following lyrics:

> Cumpleaños feliz
>   cumpleaños feliz
>   te deseamos (name) OR te deseamos todos
>   cumpleaños feliz.

There is another one, which apparently was composed by Emilio Aragón (Miliki, a famous clown), called [*Feliz en tu día*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feliz,_feliz_en_tu_d%C3%ADa):

> Feliz, feliz en tu día
>   amiguito que Dios te bendiga
>   que reine la paz en tu día
>   y que cumplas muchos más.

[See a video with Miliki and family singing it](http://youtu.be/LX2nxZvO6DQ).

It is quite known, probably because these clowns' show was very famous back in the day, but not used very much.

Comment: Cumpleaños feliz, cumpleaños feliz, te desean tus amigos de Parchís ;) (song usually heard in pubs when it's the birthday of someone)

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico we sing "**[las mañanitas](http://gomexico.about.com/od/historyculture/qt/mananitas.htm)**":

> Estas son las mañanitas que cantaba el rey David, hoy por ser tu
>   cumpleaños te las cantamos a ti, despierta (name) despierta mira que
>   ya amaneció, ya los pajarillos cantan, la luna ya se metió.

This short version is what usually people sing.